# How to find the total month between two date and also find the number of days in each month

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

What I want the Image output in my application

In the last date I want to total days

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
```

Comment: I Think you forgot the first part of the question which was to get the number of months between two dates this can be done by ((date1.Year - date2.Year) * 12) + date1.Month - date2.Month